# Getting ERROR ITMS-9000 when trying to upload an app using Application Loader

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, application-loader

When I try to upload an application to iTunes Connect using application loader, I get these errors:

> Apple's web service operation was not successful
>
> Unable to authenticate the package: (app id).itmsp
>
> ERROR ITMS-9000: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. Your application bundle's signature
>       contains code signing entitlements that are not supported on iOS. Specifically, value 
>       'development' for key 'aps-environment' in 'Payload/brainademy.app/brainademy' is not 
>       supported." at SoftwareAssets/SoftwareAsset (MZItmspSoftwareAssetPackage)

This has been happening for about 36 hours, and Apple support tells me to try again in 30 minutes (which obviously doesn't work).

I'm using the latest versions of both Xcode and application loader, I'm building using a physical iPhone, and I have the archive set to `release`. When I click `Activity...` Everything works fine, and then I see:

> ERROR ITMS-9000: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlement...

Then everything works fine again, until I see

> An error occurred talking to the iTunes Store

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your app states that you are using a Push **Development** entitlement. Only (Push) **Production** entitlements may be used to send an app to Apple.
Review your certificates (inside developer.apple.com - certificates) and locate a certificate that states:
[image: APNS Development certificate]

If you do not need that certificate, just click on the certificate and revoke it.
If you need the development certificate, it means that what you need is to generate the Production APNS certificate.

Comment: I need both and I have 2 is it fine?

Comment: Yes you can have both. That's the most usual thing, btw

Answer (score 75):

I got one because my XCode loves to play a joke on me with **Code Signing Identity** section in **Build Settings**. For *Release* it should be **iOS Distribution**, not *iOS Developer*. Sometimes it resets.

[image]

Comment: I observed when Xcode plays this "joke" on me. If I attempt to Archive with a device connected, it wants to build it for that device, and of course my device doesn't have my Distribution profile on it. Xcode offers to "fix" the issue, but if you let it, thats when the joke is on you and it switches you to iOS Developer code signing.

Comment: Also just a note that if you any today widgets etc. in your app the values also get changed from **iOS Distribution** to **iOS Developer** so they need to be changed there as well.

Comment: It seems that pulling the plug on your phone and hitting 'Archive' very shortly after will result in the same problem. WTF Xcode.

Comment: This resolved my problem. Though I kept my phone disconnected during archiving. Else it would switch back to Developer after throwing a "Distribution profile" error.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else that may be getting this error:

in `Target > Info` I changed my "Executable File" name and it threw this error.  Just leaving it alone I find is best.

Answer (score 1):

This just happened to me. The problem was simply that my production provisioning profile had expired, and XCode for some reason decided to use the development profile. Regenerating a new production provisioning profile fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

*With newer versions of Xcode, this is no longer a problem*

---

[**lnjuanj**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1776884) found [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18986067/2767207), yet there's also something else like this that could happen when your exporting an application that happened to me multiple times.

When your exporting your archive, make sure to check save as Enterprise Ad Hoc Deployment, not Submit to iOS app store, which is the default. Then, open up Application loader, and select the `.ipa` file that XCode generated.