# Invalid code signing entitlements?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, submit, runtime-error

I have found these errors while uploading the app on app store, can anyone solve this issue please?

```
Error ITMS-9000: "Invalid code signing entitlements. Your application bundle's signature contains code signing entitlement that are not supported on iOS. specifically, value '*' for key 'com.apple.developer.associated-domamains' in 
'Payload/battleofchampionsHDIOS.app/battleofchampionsHDIOS' is not support."
```

I already have tried previous methods like, disabled that `iCloud`, `**regenerated provisional profiles multiple times, refreshed the Xcode / mac / provisional profiles from Xcode**. but still having the same error again and again and again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your certificate again. Are you sure you are using correct certificate? Production environment certificate?

Refer these links

[ERROR ITMS-9000: "Missing Code Signing Entitlements. No entitlements found in bundle" - How to change app ID name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23347770/error-itms-9000-missing-code-signing-entitlements-no-entitlements-found-in-bu)

[Getting ERROR ITMS-9000 when trying to upload an app using Application Loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18969988/getting-errors-when-trying-to-upload-an-app-using-application-loader)

Comment: @NasirKhan apple using two type of certificates. Development environment and production environment. So for the testing you can use development certificate. But Appstore you should use production certificate. :)

Answer (score 11):

I resolved this issue because I had selected the "Associated Domains" entitlement (on the Apple Developer site) however in Xcode 6.1.1 seemed to not allow an app to be submitted if you have the Associated Domains switch as off in the capabilities Xcode tab.

You can therefore solve the Associated Domain issue by going to your app target in Xcode, Capabilities, Associated Domains and hitting the switch to ON if it's off. You don't have to add any info/domains but it seems to make Xcode happy!

See image below:
[image]

Alternatively if you can (and don't mind) then you could remove the Associated Domain entitlement when configuring your app on the Apple Developer site and re-download the certs/profiles.

Answer (score 2):

This issue suddenly attacked me. I upload builds frequently and nothing was changed. Just kept getting rejected from the app store for the code signing.

For me a different solution worked. In Xcode go to your App Target -> Build Settings -- check the code signing identity, on that drop down I selected my distribution code signing (I had developer selected). I changed that and it worked. Also the Provisioning Profile (still under code signing) was set to automatic which I think might play a role if this is an issue for someone.

Answer (score 1):

For me I just have to turn off Associated Domians

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check your associated domains in `Project Settings > Capabilities`
From the error, you have set that to wildcard (*) which is not allowed.

For more information about associated domains consult the [App Distribution Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html)